# Usar un HashMap para recorrer posiciones de una matriz 8x8

Tags: java, android, android-studio

resulta que estaba desarrollando una especie de "candy crush" (bejeweled) en el cual necesito recorrer de alguna manera las posiciones de mi matriz y eliminar los elementos repetidos ( que coinciden con el clickeado ).

```
public HashMap recorrerHorizontal(HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapa,int cont){
    for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.length; fila++) {
        cont = 0;
        for (int columna = 0; columna < matriz[fila].length; columna++) {

            if (matriz[fila][columna] == matriz[EnX][EnY]) {
                mapa.put(fila, columna);
                cont = cont +1;
            }
            if(matriz[fila][columna] != matriz[EnX][EnY]){
                return mapa;
            }

        }

    }
    return mapa;   
}

recorrerHorizontal(mapa,cont);

while(iterator.hasNext() && (cont > 2)){

    Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
     int laX= (int) mentry.getKey();
     int laY= (int) mentry.getValue();
     int ub = laX * 8 + laY;
     grid.getChildAt(ub).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Tengo un problema que ese doble for me va  a recorrer la matriz, encuentra los elementos iguales, los borra pero la  matriz la sigue recorriendo y me va a ir agregando a la matriz otros elementos que no quiero que esten. No sabria como decirle que pare de buscar elementos, cuando por ejemplo encuentra x elementos iguales que esten en la misma fila

Comment: La mejor manera sería separar las operaciones en métodos a parte. Si quieres detener todas las operaciones de Loop. Simplemente haz `return` una vez hayas completado la operación, si haces `break` simplemente se detendrá un ciclo. Si quieres utilizar un valor más adelante para realizar una operación con el resultado de un Loop, retorna el valor en una función. Si entendiste déjame saber.

Comment: Gracias por responder, hice un metodo que me retorne un hashMap, el momento del return se porvocaria cuando encuentre un elemento distinto. Igual no me estaria funcionando, edito el post para que lo puedas ver.

Comment: Ahí lo edite el post